# Azure Map -How to show number on grid for reference

Tags: azure-maps

Below link is example which we used but,
We want to show grid number on the map which is show in below image

https://samples.azuremaps.com/polygons/show-points-of-gridded-data-source

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by attaching the data source to a symbol layer. Here is a simple example that I just tried in the sample you referenced (you can copy/paste this right into the browser dev console and it should work):

```js
map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, { 
    iconOptions: { 
        image: 'none' 
    }, 
    textOptions: { 
        textField: ['get', 'point_count_abbreviated'] 
    }
}));
```

Note that as you zoom in you will eventually get to a point where the labels appear multiple times per grid cell. This is due to the data being split into vector tiles for performance. You can get around this by calculating the grid cell center points and using those as a seperate data source to prevent this from happening. Here are samples that show how to add labels to polygons: https://samples.azuremaps.com/?search=polygon%20label